# Change FFmpeg waveform colour overlaid over image

Tags: ffmpeg

**How can I make the waveform white in colour?** No matter what I do I get brown. This is presumably green and red combined?

```
for i in *.mp3 ; do
ffmpeg -i "$i" -loop 1 -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,format=rgba,colorkey=0x000000:0.1:0.5[fg]; \
 [1:v]scale=1280:-1,crop=iw:720[bg]; \
[bg][fg]overlay=shortest=1,format=yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a libopus "$(basename "${i/.mp3}").mkv"
 sleep 60
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each channel has it's own default color, and overlapping channels will combine colors but there are several options to deal with this.

## Choose the channel colors

[image]

```
showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:colors=white
```

## Split the channels

[image]

```
showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:colors=white:split_channels=1
```

## Make a mono waveform

[image]

```
aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:colors=white
```

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg Filter Documentation: showwaves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves)

---

### Use parameter expansion instead of `basename`

Replace `"$(basename "${i/.mp3}").mkv"` with `"${i%.mp3}.mkv"` for one less process.

Comment: Awesome. I spent hours trying to achieve it. You've helped me out there! Thx.